# JavaScript - Chained Properties on prototype with Correct 'this' Context

Tags: javascript, prototype

A bit of a long shot. But is there anyway to get chained properties on a constructor function's prototype and still have the 'this' context point to the original object instance. For instance:

```
Array.prototype.$ = {};

Array.prototype.$.where = function(selector) {
    console.log(this);
    return;
};

var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
myArray.$.where();
```

The console outputs `{ where: [Function] }`, the 'this' context is pointing to the <strike>where function</strike> $ object and not the array itself.

However, if I change it to:

```
Array.prototype.where = function(selector) {
    console.log(this);
    return;
};

var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
myArray.where();
```

It correctly outputs `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`

Comment: "the 'this' context is pointing to the where function" - no, it's pointing to the `$` object, containing the `where` function.

Comment: Ah, good point basilikum. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it, but if you cannot change initial definitions, a possible workaround is:

```
//<definitions>
Array.prototype.$ = {}; 

Array.prototype.$.where = function(selector) {
    console.log(this);
    return;
};
//</definitions>

Array.prototype.dollarCall = function(fName, arg) {
    this.$[fName].call(this,arg);
}

var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
myArray.dollarCall('where');
```

I repeat myself. This is only a workaround for specific cases. Otherwise you should use your own second method

if you can change your definition, another possible solution:

```
Array.prototype.extend = function() {
    var array = this;
    this.$ = {
        where : function() {
            console.log(array);
        }
    }
}

var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
myArray.extend();
myArray.$.where()
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` at your function is `myArray.$`, which is exactly same with `Array.prototype.$`. You can execute `console.log(myArray.$)` or `console.log(Array.prototype.$)`, they will prints same result with `myArray.$.where();`

What does it means? When you're calling `myArray.$.where();`, you're actually doing `Array.prototype.$.where();`. So it's context(`this`) becomes `Array.prototype.$`, so it will not work as you expected.

---

One more thing: [extending the DOM/built-in object prototype is generally considered harmful](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea). I strongly recommend trying another way.

Comment: I'm aware it's harmful, that's why I'm trying to extend it with only one property, the $ property. Also, I'm not trying to extend Object itself, only Array.

Comment: I came up with this approach http://jsbin.com/uwutaf/1/edit and it works. Though the syntax is a bit uglier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible this way: since `$` is a plain object, it could be referenced by many objects (even tho' in this case there's only one, which is `Array.prototype.$`) therefore from inside `$` there's no way to tell which of these references you're using to access it.

What I mean is:

```
Array.prototype.$ = {};
someOtherObject = Array.prototype.$;

Array.prototype.$.where = function(selector) {
    console.log(this);
    return;
};

var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
myArray.$.where();
console.log(myArray.$)
someOtherObject.where()
```

As Mics said, `someOtherObject` has no relation whatsoever with `myArray`.

P.S. This said, I still feel like there must be some easy way to do this without complicating the interface further...

Comment: I came up with this http://jsbin.com/uwutaf/1/edit though I feel the syntax is a bit uglier, but it works.

Comment: @SundayIronfoot this will create a complete new object with all the functions within every time you call `$`. I think you're better off if you just add the functions to the instance instead of the prototype, except maybe if you're about to create an awful lot of arrays at the same time.